# “There is a bed, two chairs and a table in the bedroom”

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is this acceptable?

> There is a bed, two chairs and a table in the bedroom.

Against these:

> 1. In the bedroom is a bed, two chairs and a table.
> 2. In the bedroom are two chairs, a bed and a table.

Comment: You should explain what the problem is, simply asking if a sentence is acceptable or not could be interpreted as a request for proofreading, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: I don't know how to explain the problem other than using an example.

Answer (score -1):

The proper sentence is in the title while examples 1 & 2 are at least missing 'there'. 
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/there-is-there-are/

Their word order (as well as omitting 'there') is less natural, but possible for speech with some contextual emphasis or for poetry:

In the bedroom 
Are two chairs,  
A bed and a table. 
Poor maiden  
Died upstairs - 
That's the end of the fable.

Comment: All three sentences are grammatical (in my dialect), the omission of "there" in examples 1 and 2 is quite common.

Comment: I agree about grammar, added a note.

Comment: I didn't downvote, maybe the user who did will retract. Clever rhyme you made up there.